# Color customization with Google forms.

Tags: html, css, rgb

Google forms is automatically altering color when I insert a custom photo banner (which does not match our brand). How and where can I enter in a specific color code (if possible)? Is there a specific format that should be used? (HTML, RGB, CMYK?)

Also, the initial box IN the email seems to be defaulting to a red/burgundy color scheme. Is this normal, and is it also able to be changed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I imagine this would probably be more appropriate posted on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, George! I'll post there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not possible. If you change the image banner it will change the colour too.

Comment: this is not look like an answer.

Comment: I'm answering by sonfirming that he cannot do it

Comment: it only suits in comment. answer is only to provide solution